# Localization is failed for a textview in storyboard but others effective

Tags: ios

This my main.strings:

```
"Sll-mr-ueA.text" = "Grassroots doctors are waiting for your valuable advice";
"Sll-mr-ueA.text" = "基层医生正等待您的宝贵意见";
```

This my storyboard file:

```
<textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" text="基层医生正等待您的宝贵意见" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Sll-mr-ueA">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="359" height="147"/>
                                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                    <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
</textView>
```

This textview load original value，but other controls effective。

Comment: Did you try to change language of your iphone?

Comment: No,I use objc_setAssociatedObject replace .lproj file,and other view is work,only this textview failed.